# Proper way to load text file containing umlauts and work with it in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to load a .txt file which represents emails containing umlauts (ä, ö, ü) into python (2.7). Afterwards I want to replace some expressions which contain these umlauts (e.g. mail.replace('Grüße', 'Gruesse')). 
I already tried different encodings of the .txt file like utf-8, unicode and ansi, but I always get decoding errors when I try to use the replace function.

What should be the proper encoding of my .txt file and how should i open respectively decode it to work with the string easily?

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: E.g. this piece of code:

with open('./positiv.txt', 'r') as f:

    pos = f.read()

print pos[0:100].replace('ö', 'oe')

Comment: It's difficult to say without a reproducible example and the _entire_ error message.  You could try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top your Python source if your have umlauts embedded in it as described in your question.